# nginx serve Elasticsearch and Kibana on the same host

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, elasticsearch, kibana

Totally new to nginx, I need a conf file to make nginx act as a reverse proxy to serve request on the same host to elasticsearch and kibana with different url path.
I mean, I want:

```
localhost/es -> localhost:9200
localhost/kibana -> localhost:5601
```

How can I make it?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, the complete answer is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name $hostname localhost;

    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file pathtofile;

    location /kibana {
        rewrite ^/kibana/(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5601/;
    }
    location ~ ^/es(.*) {
        rewrite /es/(.*) /$1  break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9200;
    }   
}
```

still, I don't know why, but Kibana first request is served very slowly (40secs). Tried with apache httpd and it's way much faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
location /es(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:9200/$args;
}

location /kibana(.*) {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5601/$args;
}
```

think there is no need in additional comments

Comment: `rewrite` instruction needed. Like `rewrite /es/(.*) /$1  break;`

Answer (score 0):

The location mappings provided by [koopa](https://serverfault.com/a/923145/509844) can be simplified to not require the rewrite command and use of regex. This is stated in the [nginx proxy_pass documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)

```
location /es/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9200/;
}

location /kibana/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5601/;
}
```